# Migrate code from SVN to GIT without losing commits history?

Tags: git, svn, logging, github, svn2git

I want to migrate an existing svn repo to git repo. I use 'svn2git'. The situation is:

SVN Repo:

- ./svn_repo/a/
- ./svn_repo/b/

I have different svn logs in folder svn_repo, 'a' and 'b'.
for example:

- svn_repo: 'svn log' -> bla, bla
- svn_repo/a: 'svn log' -> asd, asd
- svn_repo/b: 'svn log' -> 123, 123

Migration:

1. svn2git -v 'svn_repo' --trunk / --nobranches --notags
2. Create a file authors.txt with the list of conversions to make, one per line.
3. Then pass an authors option to svn2git pointing to the file: svn2git 'svn_repo' --authors ~/authors.txt
4. git remote add origin ..git_repo and then 'git push origin master'

Now:
GIT Repo:

- ./git_repo/a/
- ./git_repo/b/

Everything is good except the logs.

After migration:

- git_repo: 'git log' -> bla, bla
- git_repo/a: 'git log' -> bla, bla * (instead of asd, asd)
- git_repo/b: 'git log' -> bla, bla * (instead of 123, 123)

How can I have the same logs in git like in svn (in directory a,b etc.) after the migration?

BR

Comment: does `git log .` (in `git_repo/a` and `git_repo/b`) work as expected?

Comment: It gives me the log of the root directory, instead of git_repo/a log or git_repo/b log.